# App crashes on back press

Tags: android, kotlin

I converted my app to kotlin and since when I call `onBackPressed()` in my `SettingsActivity` (`GameActivity` is the parent activity) my app crashes with a `Parameter specified as non-null is null`.
But when I use

```
val intent = Intent(this, GameActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

instead the app does not crash. Both actions lead to the same activity.
Why's that and how can I resolve it?

The error happens in this line:
[image]

Here is the stacktrace:

[image]

My onActivityResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    when (requestCode) {
        SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE -> recreate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Which parameter? The stacktrace gives you specific information on where your app failed.

Comment: It told me here: http://d.zkr.io/Yq3Zqx

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant information in the question itself, not as links to third-party websites.

Comment: This is not the correct line. No code is executed at that line, so it can't cause an exception.

Comment: I included the stacktrace. The line with the arrow points to the line in the other picture

Comment: It says the error is your onActivityResult method, add it to the question

Comment: And please post text here, not screenshots.

Comment: But why does it link to this line then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the parameter in your `onActivityResult` to nullable:

```
onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
```

The error code says that data is null, but your parameter is non-nullable.

Comment: Changing parameter to nullable will fix the crash but may not be the correct approach. Data is null means setResult is not called by second activity. I will fix the issue by calling setResult before calling onBackPressed

Comment: Well that's why the `resultCode` is there as a parameter. Maybe it's intended that result is not set, however data is nullable and should therefore be marked as such.

Comment: Yes, my point here is we should first check if we are missing any case where data is not being setup properly before marking it as nullable. If there is no use-case where data will be null then it should not be marked as nullable. So that, we can catch the bugs when data is null because of logical error.